# How to get index number of an item in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

This is my code:

```
foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    string i = item.ToString();
    if (item.ToString()== "myItem")
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString(); // how to get the founded item index?
        break; 
    }    
}
```

There is a loop in a `ListBox` for finding a specific item. After finding that item I want to know what is the index of that item in the `ListBox`?

Comment: Try listBox1.Items.IndexOf(item)

Comment: The easiest is to use `for` instead of `foreach` and check `listBox1.Items` value by index. As soon as you find item you search for you have index at your will.

Comment: @user1275011 solved! thanks